# How do i load data to a drop down on view that already bound with a collection?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

i have a view that is bound with the `IEnumerable<ProductCategoryViewModel>`
in this view there is a drop down box with the values **search type values** so i can search a product category by either code or name.

here is the controller:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{


    List<SelectListItem> list = new List<SelectListItem> { 
        new SelectListItem {Text="By Code", Value="1", Selected=true}, 
        new SelectListItem {Text="By Name", Value="2"}
    };

    var categories = _db.mt_ProductCategories
                        .Select(
                        p => new ProductCategoriesViewModel
                        {
                            Id = p.Id,
                            Name = p.CatName,
                            CatCode = p.CatCode, SearchTypes=list
                        });

    if (Request.IsAjaxRequest())
    {
        return PartialView("_ProductCategoryList", categories);
    }

    return View(categories);

}
```

here is the **ViewModel**

```
public class ProductCategoriesViewModel
{
   public int Id { get; set; }
   public string  CatCode { get; set; }
   public string Name { get; set; }


   public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> SearchTypes { get; set; }
   public string SearchType { get; set; }
}
```

here is **view**

```
    @model IEnumerable<eComm1.Models.ProductCategoriesViewModel>

    @using (Ajax.BeginForm("Search", "ProductCategory",
        new AjaxOptions
        {
            HttpMethod = "POST",
            UpdateTargetId = "prod-grid",
            InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace,
            OnSuccess = "loaddivdata"

        }))
    { 
        //i need to put the drop down here but since i passed a collection it does not show the property "SearchType". the code should be like below but errors
@Html.DropDownListFor(m=>m.SearchType, Model.SearchTypes)
    }
```

How do i access the property SearchType in my current view?

Comment: You need a view model which contains `string SearchType`, `IEnumerable<SelectListItem> SearchTypes` and `IEnumerable<ProductCategoriesViewModel> ProductCategories` and remove the `SearchType` and `SearchTypes` properties from your existing `ProductCategoriesViewModel`. In fact `ProductCategoriesViewModel` may not even be required - the view model could just have `IEnumerable<ProductCategories> ProductCategories`

Comment: @StephenMuecke that mate, if you could post that an answer i could give points

Comment: Are you initially displaying the product categories? (I suspect you don't even need the `IEnumerable<ProductCategories> ProductCategories` property in your view model (and if you do, you could use `@Html.Action()` to render it).

Comment: @StephenMuecke yes im displaying the product categories list as partial

Comment: OK, then I will suggest a better approach - I'm assuming you have a `Search(int SearchType)` method in `ProductCategoryController`

Comment: yea with the signature Search(String searchText, string searchType)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a view model that has properties for `SearchType` and `SearchType` and in the view use a single instance of that view model (and initially generate the list of `ProductCategories` by calling `@Html.Action()`).

```
public class ProductSearchVM
{
  public string searchText { get; set; }
  public string SearchType { get; set; }
  public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> SearchTypes { get; set; }
}
```

and in the controller

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
  ProductSearchVM model = new ProductSearchVM
  {
    SearchType = "1", // this is how you set the selected value
    SearchTypes = new List<SelectListItem>
    {
      new SelectListItem { Text = "By Code", Value = "1" }, // no point adding Selected = true; - its ignored by the HtmlHelper
      new SelectListItem { Text = "By Name", Value = "2" }
    }
  };
  return View(model)
}
```

and in the view

```
@model ProductSearchVM
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("Search", "ProductCategory", new AjaxOptions { ... }))
{ 
    @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.SearchType, Model.SearchTypes)
    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.searchText)
}
<div id="prod-grid">
  @Html.Action("Search", "ProductCategory") // optionally add new { searchType = "1" }?
</div>
```